# Can't find simgrid/msg.h of simgrid

Tags: c, simgrid

I installed simgrid according to instruction in INSTALL file:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/SimGrid  -Denable_maintainer_mode=off -Denable_java=on -Denable_scala=off -Denable_lua=off -Denable_smpi=on -Denable_model-checking=off

make 
sudo make install
```

But I can't find msg.h file in include directory:

[image]

What did I make incorrectly?

Comment: Could you specify the version of SimGrid that you are using? The platf_generator.h file was removed in 3.13 AFAIK.

Comment: @MartinQuinson, I use 3.13 version. I should look for #include <Msg/msg.h>, not <simgrid/msg.h>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are definitely not using a 3.13 version of SimGrid but at most a 3.11. I'm certain because the file you are using (msg/msg.h) does not work anymore since then. Plus, 3.13 introduces many files that should appear on that screenshot.

Could you please fix your question, or close it ?